# How to disable Chrome's session restore warning using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, windows, google-chrome, chromium

How to reboot the Chromium/Google Chrome (kiosk mode) in Windows via NodeJS so that it normally on restart starts the browser as it was used by a normal human? (when i use nodeJS every single time on restart of Chromium/Google chrome keep showing me that ugly/annoying/deadly popup on right top corner)

NodeJS: tell chrome to switch off

[image]

NodeJS: tell chrome to start now: on every single start it keeps opening that ugly popup on the right top corner and there is no way to remove that without human involved

[image]

```
var wait_seconds = null;

function reboot_chrome() {
  // taskkill /f /im chrome.exe
  run_cmd( "taskkill", ["/f", "/im", "chrome.exe"], function(text) { 
    console.log (text);
  });

  //$ cat C:/Python27/run.bat:
  //@echo off
  //@start /b cmd /c "C:\Users\tpt\AppData\Local\Chromium\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk

  wait_seconds = setTimeout(function() {
    run_cmd("C:\\Python27\\run.bat", [], function(text){
      console.log(text);
    });
  }, 20000);

}
```

Comment: You could use the --app-auto-launched option too when starting chrome via cli

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `--incognito` or `--disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars` switches, but the browser wouldn't behave completely as expected.

The cleanest way would be to change the `exit_type` in the preferences of the user profile. Here's a small example doing exactly that:

```
var fs   = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

//----------------------------------------------------
function restartChrome(){
    stopChrome();
    setTimeout(startChrome, 20000);
}

//----------------------------------------------------
function startChrome(){
    // change this path to your application path
    exec('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome" --kiosk')
}

//----------------------------------------------------
function stopChrome(){
    exec("taskkill /IM chrome.exe /f");
    setExitType();
}

//----------------------------------------------------
function setExitType(callback){
    // change this path to your session preferences path
    var preferencesPath = path.join(process.env["USERPROFILE"], "AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Preferences");

    fs.readFile(preferencesPath, "utf8", function(err, data){
        if (err) { return callback && callback(err); }

        var txt = data.replace(/exit_type":"Crashed/g,   'exit_type":"None')
                      .replace(/exited_cleanly":false/g, 'exited_cleanly":true');
        fs.writeFile(preferencesPath, txt, "utf8", callback);
    });
}

restartChrome();
```

Remember to adjust the paths for the application and preferences file as marked in the comments.